# Mutually Exclusive Data Attribute Selectors

Tags: javascript, jquery, custom-data-attribute

Is it possible to select elements based on mutually exclusive data attributes, for example: I'd like to `.show()` any `div`s with data attribute of `country="united-kingdom"` and also with `type="partner"` OR `"director"`? Something like:

```
$('.post[data-country="united-kingdom"]&[data-type="partner,director"]').show();
```

or

```
$('.post[data-country="united-kingdom"]&[data-type="partner"]or[data-type="director"]').show();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'd like to .show() any divs with data attribute of country="united-kingdom" and also with type="partner" OR "director"?

Then you want a [selector *group*](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#grouping):

```
$('.post[data-country="united-kingdom"][data-type="partner"], .post[data-country="united-kingdom"][data-type="director"]').show();
```

That says: Match any element which

- Has class `post`, has `data-country` set to `united-kingdom`, and has `data-type` set to `partner`

  or
- Has class `post`, has `data-country` set to `united-kingdom`, and has `data-type` set to `director`

The "or" part comes from the `,`, which is what makes it a selector group rather than a single selector.

---

In a comment, you've said:

> The user might select ten or more of each taxonomy term which requires generating loads of permutations of this conditional.

In that case, you may be better off with `filter`:

```
var countries = ["united-kingdom"];  // This would be created from inputs
var types = ["partner", "director"]; // This too
```

then

```
var results = $(".post[data-country][data-type]").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return countries.indexOf($this.attr("data-country") != -1 &&
           types.indexOf($this.attr("data-type") != -1;
});
```

In ES2016 or above, you could use [`Array#includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) — which gives you a simple boolean — instead of `Array#indexOf` which you have to check against -1; and there'a polyfill you can use in ES2015 and earlier...:

```
var results = $(".post[data-country][data-type]").filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return countries.includes($this.attr("data-country") &&
           types.includes($this.attr("data-type");
});
```

This can even be taken further:

```
var criteria = {};
// From inputs, ...
criteria["country"] = ["united-kingdom"];
criteria["type"] = ["parter", "director"];
```

then

```
var keys = Object.keys(criteria);
var selector= ".post" + keys.map(function(key) {
    return "[data-" + key + "]";
}).join();
var results = $(selector).filter(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    return keys.every(function(key) {
        return criteria[key].includes($this.attr("data-" + key));
    });
});
```

And as long as we're thinking about ES2015 and ES2016:

```
const keys = Object.keys(criteria);
const results = $(selector).filter(() => {
    const $this = $(this);
    return keys.every(key => criteria[key].includes($this.attr("data-" + key)));
});
```

or if you really want to go crazy:

```
const keys = Object.keys(criteria);
const results = $(selector).filter(() =>
    keys.every(key => criteria[key].includes(this.getAttribute("data-" + key)))
);
```

Comment: This gets the results that I'm after. I guess I was after something a little shorter :-). The user might select ten or more of each taxonomy term which requires generating loads of permutations of this selector group.

Comment: @KevinNugent: In that case, you may be better off with `filter`; I've added a note at the end.

Comment: Thanks @T.J. Crowder. I'm trying these out right now.

Comment: That's working like a charm @T.J. Crowder. Thanks for the detailed explanation. I have a follow up question: I've also got a 'show all' option on each taxonomy menu which empties the relevant array - how would you suggest I cater for this within the filter function? Currently it interprets it is 'no countries' but I'd like it to interpret as 'all countries'.

Comment: @KevinNugent: I'd change the condition in `key.every`: `key.every(key => !criteria[key] || criteria[key].includes(this.getAttribute("data-" + key)))` E.g., so it's true if there's a blank value for the criterion.

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple selectors separated by a comma

```
$('.post[data-country="united-kingdom"][data-type="artist"], .post[data-country="united-kingdom"][data-type="partner"]').show();
```

Or use a filter with a selector

```
$('.post[data-country="united-kingdom"]').filter('[data-type="artist"], [data-type="partner"]').show();
```

or a filter with a callback

```
var countries = ["united-kingdom", "india", "france"],
    types     = ["artist", "partner"];

$('.post').filter(function() {
    return types.indexOf( $(this).data('type') ) !== -1 &&
           contries.indexOf( $(this).data('coutry') ) !== -1;
}).show()
```

Comment: I don't think that's quite it, I should clarify... I have a couple of taxonomy menus: country and type. The user will be able to select multiple from each list so might request results matching country: uk OR ireland OR france AND partner or artist. So if a post was listed as data-country="France" and data-type="artist" it would be returned. I'm adding and removing the values to/from a couple or arrays and then filtering the content using .show().

Comment: You can use a filter with a callback and filter just about any data-attribute you want, but you have be more specific as to what it is you're trying to do here ?